# Strangeness with filtering in R and showing summary of filtered data

Tags: r

I have a data frame loaded using the CSV Library in R, like

```
mySheet <- read.csv("Table.csv", sep=";")
```

I now can print a summary on that mySheet object

```
summary(mySheet)
```

and it will show me a summary for each column, for example, one column named Diagnose has the unique values RCM, UCM, HCM and it shows the number of occurences of each of these values.

I now filter by a diagnose, like

```
subSheet <- mySheet[mySheet$Diagnose=='UCM',]
```

which seems to be working, when I just type subSheet in the console it will print only the rows where the value has been matched with 'UCM'

However, if I do a summary on that subSheet, like

```
summary(subSheet)
```

it still 'knows' about the other two possibilities RCM and HCM and prints those having a value of 0. However, I expected that the new created object will NOT know about the possible values of the original mySheet I initially loaded.

Is there any way to get rid of those other possible values after filtering? I also tried subset but this one just seems to be some kind of shortcut to '[' for the interactive mode... I also tried DROP=TRUE as option, but this one didn't change the game.

Totally mind squeezing :D Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are dealing with here are [factors](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/factors.html) from reading the csv file.  You can get `subSheet` to forget the missing factors with

```
subSheet$Diagnose <- droplevels(subSheet$Diagnose)
```

or

```
subSheet$Diagnose <- subSheet$Diagnose[ , drop=TRUE]
```

just before you do `summary(subSheet)`.

Personally I dislike factors, as they cause me too many problems, and I only convert strings to factors when I really need to. So I would have started with something like

```
mySheet <- read.csv("Table.csv", sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! that solves this and a succeeding problem.